# Unable to join Battlefield 3 multiplayer

Tags: battlefield-3

Whenever i try to join a multiplayer server on BF3 I get this error message from the game manager:

> Game disconnected: your connection to the server timed out.

I've searched online and [found out](http://www.enterbf3.com/topic/3933-connection-timed-out-problem-solved/) that I should stop UPnP Device Host" and the "SSDP Discovery" processes. I also turned network discovery off, but when i did that the Windows Firewall (which I disable because I have Norton) got automatically enabled.

Even after i Did so it is still not working

Comment: So do you or do you not still have the problem?

Comment: this happens anyway. Try 3 of 4 times. If it always happens :/ welcome to bf3s stupid webpage interface.

Comment: i've still got the problem and it happens every single time

Comment: I had similar problems and the source of problems was my router. After I upgraded the firmware, it works flawlessly (for now)

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off your router and leave it off for ten seconds and turn it back on it might take a while completely turn back on. Just wait til all the lights stop blinking. I've had this problem before.